# Problem with admin columns

Tags: wp-admin, screen-columns

The title is showing but the content is empty..
I tried following few tutorials time after time but i guess i miss something..
How can i get it to echo 'test' on each col please?

```
// ADD NEW COLUMN
function pslider_columns_head($defaults) {
    $defaults['show_on_page'] = 'Shown on page';
    return $defaults;
}

// SHOW THE VALUE
function pslider_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'show_on_page') {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'pslider_columns_head');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'pslider_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly here. It adds a nuew columen with "Show on page" title; each row is filled with "test".

Comment: But i don't understand why this code won't add it..
What am i missing?

Comment: As I said, it adds the column and echoes "test" correctly. Your problem is not in the coded you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem.. The website was using a plugin for adding the new post types and they were set to Hierarchical. Once i changed that everything started to work